# clang-tidy: Blacklist some checks (or regex for checks)

Tags: clang-tidy

I agree with the majority of the `clang-tidy` checks, but some I don't see tremendous value in. Mostly these are the `fuschia*` checks, such as the default argument warnings:

```
error: calling a function that uses a default argument is disallowed [fuchsia-default-arguments...
```

Therefore I would like to know how to run all of the checks except the `fuschia` ones. Right now, I just check everything in Cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY
        clang-tidy;
        -header-filter=.;
        -checks=*;
        -warnings-as-errors=*;)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang-tidy allows you to use positive and negative globs in specifying checks. Just use `-` as a prefix when specifying checks you want to exclude. In your case:

```
-checks=*,-fuchsia*;
```

If you want to verify which checks are enabled you can run a command:

```
$ clang-tidy -checks=*,-fuchsia* -list-checks
```